# can updates be automated without all the fuss?

Tags: updates, shutdown

I would like to have the system automatically check for and install updates then shut down when I am done for the day.  perhaps an application or script.  I wrote bash scripts in 2000 but have no idea how to do one for gnome.

Comment: Your Ubuntu system does something quite close to this already. Your system checks for deb security upgrades daily, and silently installs them. Your system checks for snap upgrades four times daily, and silently installs them.

Comment: Is the shutdown-at-the-end-of-the-day only when upgrading? Or every day?

Comment: I meant when i shut down for the day. It could also do file transfers and cloud backups if the great gurus felt like adding such things.  on dos bbs we used to leave the machine on and transfer our "echo" files at night when calling was cheaper.

Comment: There are two big problems with doing actions-at-shutdown. The first is the lots of folks don't like it: Windows' lengthy "don't turn me off" is among it's most *disliked* features. The second is that it's trivial to bypass (by holding down the power button or unplugging). On laptops, this is unreliable, since the battery might die before shutdown actions complete, leaving a potentially broken system. This is why your system does most housekeeping during boot instead of during shutdown.

Comment: If you want to set shutdown tasks and are likely to do a proper shutdown each time, look up how to create systemd services that use systemd's shutdown.target.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way to do this with regular updates, but you can definitely do it with security updates. In fact, Ubuntu does this by default.

If you are using vanilla Ubuntu, just open up the "Software and Updates" application, and click on the "Updates" tab, and set "Security Updates" to "Download and Install Automatically". You will also need to make sure you are subscribed to "Security and Recommended Updates".

As for shutting down the system automatically when you are done, there is no way to do that in vanilla Ubuntu, but you can certainly automatically put the system into "suspend" (sleep) mode after a certain about of time of inactivity (in fact, vanilla Ubuntu also does this by default). Just go into "Settings" > "Power" > "Automatic Suspend".